# Retrieve the child model of a record in Yii Framework

Tags: php, oop, model, yii

I am trying to understand how to get the model for a child class of a CActiveRecord model.

I have the following two basic classes:

- Class `User` extending `CActiveRecord`
- Class `Tutor` extending `User`

The connection between them is the `id` of the table `users` being a `fk` in table `tutors`. In my current app I am instanciating the `User` class, but I also need the data from the `Tutor`.

The relations were set by gii as follows:

```
For User class:
public function relations()
    {
        return array(
            'tutor' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Tutors', 'user_id'),
        );
    }


For Tutor class:
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Users', 'user_id'),
    );
}
```

How can I do so that I can get with an object populated with data from both models?

**Note:** My database tables are named at *plural*, while models are at *singular*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you query the active record model it should bring in the related objects automatically (provided you have set up their relationships properly). Something like the following with give you a start.

```
$users=User::model()->findAll();
```

Depending on what you are doing with the data you will need to decide if you wish to lazily fetch the related tables or eagerly fetch them. The following will eagerly fetch the records.

```
$users=User::model()->with('tutor')->findAll();
```

The Yii documentation on this subject is very good and well worth a read:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#performing-relational-query

Comment: Thanks, i was able to figure out how to get the objects.

Comment: I'm using Yii2 and returning data in json format. I can't include child with 'with'.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the siblings of an object can be accessed in Yii by simply using the following command:

```
$model->tutors
```

Where `tutors` represents *the table corresponding to the sibling*. If the relationship with the children is `HAS_MANY`, the command will return *one or more arrays*, each containing an instance of the sibling. If it is 1:1 (`HAS_ONE`) relationship, the command will return the object directly.